# How to use a swift class with a generic type in objective c

Tags: objective-c, swift, generics

I have the following swift class with a NumericType T.

```
@objc class MathStatistics<T: NumericType> : NSObject {
        var numbers = [T]()

        func sum() -> T? {
            if numbers.count == 0 {
                return nil
            }

            var sum = T(0)

            for value in numbers {
                sum = sum + value
            }
            return sum
        }
    }
```

In swift a initialize the class object as follows:

```
let statistics = MathStatistics<Double>()
```

How do I initialize the same object in Objective C?
The following line does not set the numeric type T.

```
MathStatistics *stats = [[MathStatistics alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't. As listed in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_78):

> You’ll have access to anything within a class or protocol that’s
> marked with the @objc attribute as long as it’s compatible with
> Objective-C. This excludes Swift-only features such as those listed
> here:
>
> - Generics
> - Tuples
> - Enumerations defined in Swift
> - Structures defined in Swift
> - Top-level functions defined in Swift
> - Global variables defined in Swift
> - Typealiases defined in Swift
> - Swift-style variadics
> - Nested types
> - Curried functions

You'd have to get rid of generics in your class. Then you can use it in Objective-C