# SWIFT 3.0 migration error - Extension of a generic Obj-C class cannot access the class' generic parameter at runtime

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, swift3, nsfastenumeration

I have this code working fine in Swift 2.

```
extension PHFetchResult: Sequence {
     public func makeIterator() -> NSFastEnumerationIterator {
         return NSFastEnumerationIterator(self)
     }
}
```

Since I upgraded to Swift 3

> Extension of a generic Objective-C class cannot access the class's generic parameters at runtime

I have no idea on how to fix this. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Problem was reported here: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1576

But in the end you can't use `for in` with PHFetchResult in Swift 3.0. Let's see some examples:

```
let collections = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .any, options: nil)
let collectionLists = PHCollectionList.fetchCollectionLists(with: .momentList, subtype: .momentListYear, options: nil)
let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: nil)
```

You can either use the built-in enumeration of PHFetchResult (my recommended solution):

```
collections.enumerateObjects(_:) { (collection, count, stop) in
    //...
}
collectionLists.enumerateObjects(_:) { (collectionList, count, stop) in
    //...
}
assets.enumerateObjects(_:) { (asset, count, stop) in
    //...
}
```

Or access each object by its index:

```
for idx in 0 ..< collections.count {
    let collection = collections[idx]
    // ...
}
for idx in 0 ..< collectionLists.count {
    let collectionList = collectionLists[idx]
    // ...
}
for idx in 0 ..< assets.count {
    let asset = assets[idx]
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pulling from Realm, you may be able to get around this by extending a subclass of what you want to conform to Sequence and put the `makeIerator` function there.

```
// Sequence conformance for ClassA is provided by ProtocolX's `makeIterator()` implementation.
extension ClassA: Sequence {}

extension ProtocolX {
    // Support Sequence-style enumeration
    public func makeIterator() -> RLMIterator {
        return RLMIterator(collection: self)
    }
}
```

You can see the full code at https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/Realm/Swift/RLMSupport.swift

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wrapper type as [suggested by Swift engineer Jordan Rose](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3328?focusedCommentId=19919&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-19919) on the bug report:

> ```
> import Photos
>
> struct ResultSequence<Element: AnyObject>: Sequence {
>   var result: PHFetchResult<Element>
>   init(_ result: PHFetchResult<Element>) {
>     self.result = result
>   }
>   func makeIterator() -> NSFastEnumerationIterator {
>     return NSFastEnumerationIterator(self.result)
>   }
> }
>
>
> func test(_ request: PHFetchResult<PHCollection>) {
>   for elem in ResultSequence(request) {
>     print(elem)
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to fix that, you might need to refactor your code or use some other techniques.

you can refer to this:

[How to use a swift class with a generic type in objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361848/how-to-use-a-swift-class-with-a-generic-type-in-objective-c)

docs:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_78